# Job title question

Tags: new-job, title

I am currently working in a project management role, where I have been promoted, and I have the option to change my title to lead project manager or Senior project manager, my goal is to work at upper management at some point and I am not sure which title is going to add the most value moving forward.

Comment: This question is almost completely opinion-based as written, and is also off-topic for being about a specific choice. Can you edit to make this easier to answer objectively?

Comment: I will be , and I will be working a lot with upper management to kick off new teams at program level

Comment: Go with the title "Senior project manager". The word "Senior" seems to be more impactful than "Lead".

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Based on what? Do you have evidence to back that up, or are you just stating an opinion?

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Reinstate Monica, For example, you have the  title "Senior Vice President" of a company, which sounds cool because Senior VP is clearly the BOSS of VPs. But, you don't hear "Lead Vice President" of any company.  Similarly, you have "Senior Managers" and not "Lead Manager" because Senior Managers are the BOSS of Managers. Some times, a team lead is basically the same as coworkers, and the only extra thing the team lead does is to write reports to the manager.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 on the contrary, being "Lead XYZ" sounds as if you're the top of _all_ of the XYZs - higher up than all of the "Senior XYZ" employees... There may be many Seniors but only one Lead.

Comment: I went with Lead in the end, after talking to external recruiters it is higher than Senior plus I am leading as part of my day to day responsibilities. Lead also implies Seniority. There is also difference between ‘team lead’ and ‘lead’, lead is the equivalent of a head of that work, team lead only leads a single team

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what conveys more responsibility, but personally, I lose any respect for titles where in the end the person did not actually do what their title suggest.

*Do* you lead other project managers? Are there multiple project managers assigned to a project and you lead them? Or maybe there are multiple project managers on multiple projects and you organize and lead their work?

If that is the case, you are a "Lead Project Manager".

If you are an experienced, veteran project manager, that can teach other project managers how to do their job better, then you are a senior project manager.

I don't think it is about what sounds better, it is about whether you actually do what the title says. If it's just an empty title and people find out in the interview that it's just that, none of those is going to help you.

So, you have to pick yourself. What is it you actually do?

Comment: Upvote for recommending the truth

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a great example of how meaningless and superficial titles can be in many firms. And how, like medals, they are often freely handed out to boost egos, in lieu of monetary compensation. (I've especially observed this with US firms and all their President's and VP titles.)

I am ofcourse, not trying to disparage you or your professional achievement. A healthy ego boost is often necessary to feel valued and derive increased job satisfaction in any profession.

The point I am trying to make is that each company has their own interpretation of what a designation means. There is only a loosely defined common understanding for common titles in most industries. We can't reasonably tell you if lead project manager or Senior project manager in your company means the same as it it does in another firm.

You have titles / designation, and then there are roles and responsibilities associated with them.

For example, in one firm a Project Manager may only be expected to do the role of PM and manage a project with their team. In another company, a Project Manager may be given an additional role / responsibility to work with management to generate additional revenue from the client whose project the PM is managing.

In another words, the roles and responsibilities and the remuneration of an employee is a better indicator of how much a company values an employee. And how invested they are in them.

If the titles and promotion paths are not clear to you, ask your boss and / or HR to clarify them for you. If you want to move to management position in the future, you need to show your value by asking for more responsibilities and more remuneration. (Both are tricky things - management will be glad to give you more work, and then delay promoting you. Asking for incentives is always unpopular with management. You'll have to master negotiating these to be management material. And finally, management positions are rarer the higher you go up the ladder. So even if you are qualified, often there won't be any position to fill so you need to realistically assess your goals.)